# How to subtract the value of a row from the previous value using a Reporting Services Expression?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Using the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT     
   TOP (100) PERCENT 
   ID_BADGE, 
   LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(TIME_TRX AS varchar), 6), 2) 
     + ':' + SUBSTRING(LEFT(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(TIME_TRX AS varchar), 6), 4), 3, 2) AS ClockTime, 
   DATE_TRX, SEQ_REC, ROWID
FROM
   omi.TAHIST_ZERO
WHERE     
   (ID_BADGE = '     ' + @Badge) 
   AND (DATE_TRX BETWEEN @Date AND @Date2) 
   AND (SEQ_REC IN ('0', '1000')) 
   AND (CODE_TRX IN ('100', '101'))
ORDER BY 
   DATE_TRX, TIME_TRX
```

I have created the following table:

[image: screenshot of ssrs table]

Using a **Reporting Services Expression** I want to subtract the second value of ClockTime from the third value of ClockTime.

I looked through the VB Functions and all I could find were First, Last, Min, and Max, not second or third.

Comment: Google has [lots of help here](https://www.google.com/search?q=subtract+previous+row+sql).

Comment: Second that. Probably the word "[Previous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200.aspx)" is key here.

Comment: Not in T-SQL I am trying to do this through a VB Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could achieve this using the SSRS Previous function:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)